# React Native no muestra los cambios realizados automáticamente

Tags: react-native

React Native no me está mostrando los cambios automáticamente, al momento de guardar los cambios en el archivo App.js. He leído en varios sitios, las soluciones, pero ninguna me ha funcionado. He hecho las pruebas tanto en el emulador de android, como el teléfono físico.
Tengo la versión de Node.JS 12.18.3 LTS y React Native 0.63.
El proceso de instalación que he realizado es el de los tutoriales y también el de la página de reactnative.dev.

El proceso que tengo que llevar a cabo es el siguiente:

1. Primero debo ejecutar el siguiente código:

```
react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res
```

2. Luego debo de ejecutar lo siguiente: `react-native run-android` o `npx react-native run-android`

Si he buscado en google, he hecho pruebas y nada. De hecho el primer error que me da siempre que inicializo el proyecto es el de metro bundle. Como que no tuviese un metro bundle corriendo. Pero después que ejecuto el primer código que les puse, tiene éxito y ahí si muestra el contenido de la App.js.

Si alguien pudiese ayudarme, les agradecería.

Nota: uso windows 10 de 64 bits, tengo descargado la API 29 y 30 de android, también he descargardo NDK (Side by side) y CMake en android studio.
Y mis variables de entorno están de la siguiente manera:

[image: Variables de entorno 1]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo solucioné de la siguiente manera por si alguien le sirve.
Suponiendo que mi dirección IP es: 192.168.56.2...
Primero puse mi dirección IP en el navegador junto al puerto **192.168.56.2:8081** . Y me dí cuenta, que EDBPostgres estaba corriendo en ese puerto.

Así que para correr la aplicación ejecuté:

1. Primero, para el metro bundle: `react-native start --port 8084 --reset-cache`
2. Luego para ejecutar la app:  `react-native run-Android --port 8084`

Y también en el emulador, fui a configuraciones y en Debug server host & port for device le puse la ip con el puerto **192.168.56.2:8084** .

Hice un Reload en el metro bundle, y funcionó.